# Read in lines from text line as separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, readlines

I have a text file containing lines of strings that resemble an array format. I initially had a list of numpy arrays, and read them into the file like this, where each array is about 5 floats:

```
import numpy as np
parameters = [np.array(...), np.array(...), ...]
with open('params.txt', 'w') as f:
   for param in parameters:
       f.write(str(param)+'\n')
```

Now I'd like to read them back out, as a list of separate arrays. I'm having issues with this however -- below is what I'm trying to do:

```
parameters = []
with open('params.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        parameters.append(np.array(line))
```

But now when I later try to index elements in these arrays and use list comprehension, like: `[params[2] for params in parameters]`, I get this error: `IndexError: too many indices for array`.

I have also tried reading them out with `line.split(',')`, but this didn't give me what I wanted and just messed up the formatting further. How can I accomplish this?

The format of my text file:

```
[242.1383, 131.087, 1590.853, 1306.09, 783.979]
[7917.102, 98.12, 21.43, 13.1383, 6541.33]
[823.74, 51.31, 9622.434, 974.11, 980.177]
...
```

What I want:

```
parameters = [np.array([242.1383, 131.087, 1590.853, 1306.09, 783.979]), np.array([7917.102, 98.12, 21.43, 13.1383, 6541.33]), np.array([823.74, 51.31, 9622.434, 974.11, 980.177]), ...]
```

Comment: If you want to address the problem at the source, use .npy files (numpy.load, numpy.save), or numpy.loadtxt, numpy.savetxt...

Comment: I tried `np.loadtxt` also, but get an error like this: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[392.668,'`. I understand that's because I have whole arrays (with their formatting) saved as strings, not just the numbers. But unfortunately I cannot go back and save it in a different format.

Comment: You could use `np.genfromtxt` and supply a [`converters` argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#the-converters-argument): `converters={0: (lambda x:float(x.lstrip('['))), 4: (lambda x:float(x.rstrip(']')))}` (I don't know if that last column (4) comes in with a newline, if so you'll need to strip that as well.)

Comment: Writing a the `str(arr)` of an array is not a good idea.  It includes `[]` (and `...` for long arrays) which complicate the read.  But having done so, you now have to strip off those extra [] before parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a slightly simpler way to accomplish this without having to worry about all the string parsing, using regex:

```
import re
parameters = []
with open('params.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        set = [float(value) for value in re.findall('\d+\.?\d*', line)]
        parameters.append(np.array(set))
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
parameters = []
for line in f.readlines():
    y = [value for value in line.split()]
    parameter.append( y )
```

would be easier if I knew what the text file looked like if would would show the format of the text file you're trying to read from

Comment: Please see my edit for an example of the format of my file and what I'd like from it. The problem is the new line after each line, and the fact that they are strings (including the `[` and `]` characters). I tried your suggestion just now but it didn't work with the formatting.

Comment: Read about python string methods. the brackets can be removed with str.replace, and the line endings with str.strip